# Custom UITableViewCell Highlighting on Touch-Down

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to implement a custom behavior when a user has a touch-down on a UITableViewCell. The closest thing I can find to getting info on when the user has a touch-down is the delegate method `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. However, the documentation states:

> This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their
>   finger; the row isn't selected until then, although it is
>   highlighted on touch-down. You can use
>   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to disable the appearance of the
>   cell highlight on touch-down. This method isn’t called when the table
>   view is in editing mode (that is, the editing property of the table
>   view is set to YES) unless the table view allows selection during
>   editing (that is, the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of the
>   table view is set to YES).

Any advice on detecting this touch-down to do my custom highlight behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make a cell subclass and then implement whatever changes in the `touchesBegan:` method, and then remove those changes in `touchesEnded:`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and override the method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and maybe, depending on your needs:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and don't forget to call super!

---

Apple's documentation:

- [`setHighlighted:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW69)
- [`setSelected:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW3)

---

Update (25/08/2015):

In Swift, I'd do something like this:

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
            else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }
```